# Declare variable to use inside @helper.repeat - PlayFramework

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to use helper.repeat to create several input elements. But I want to declare the input tags as html instead of using @helper.input methods. But to do that I have to use a @index inside this loop. I am unable to instantiate and increase this variable. I tried something like the code below but I this output appear in html page:
    BaseScalaTemplate(play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat$@5a8a0ced) = {0}
is output in html.

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">

                @index = {0}
            @helper.repeat(questionForm("answer.alternatives"), min = 7) { (alternative) =>
                <div class="checkbox">

                    <input type="checkbox" value="@alternative("correct") ">
                    <input type="text" id="answer_alternatives_(@index)_text" name="answer.alternatives[@index].text" value="">
                </div>
            }
            </div>
        </div>
```

Is there another maybe cleaner way to do what I want? Maybe with @for?

I use playframework 2.4.6 with Java8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playframework will let you do what you need, but you will have to do it in another way.

1) Your form definition will have a `Seq[String]` to save the results that come from the template.

2) Your form definition will need to include this change. In your case:

```
"answer_alternatives" -> seq(nonEmptyText)
```

3) Change the name and id from the template to `@{alternative.name}` so Playframework can link your input text to the sequence of String.

```
<input type="text" id="@{alternative.name}" name="@{alternative.name}" value="">
```

Comment: I'm new in play framework. if there isn't a more natural way to do I think it's not  like that kind of thing usually is done? How this type of mapping is usually implemented? Should I create a kind of TransferObject to hold the views inputs? Or maybe use DynamicForm and disassociate the model from view until it reachs the Controller layer?

Comment: As it is another question (which will need a long reply), I would create another question asking exactly what you need with an example.

Comment: I asked another related question 2 days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35664642/4785114 What I want is more or less but I want to use pure html in forms without the @helper class