# Play Framework pass dynamically added row data from tables to controller

Tags: playframework

I am learning Play Framework. In the view I have a table which creates a dynamic row upon clicking a "+" button. The user can add many rows and fill in the data and submit the form. How can I get the data from each row in my controller(java)?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664642/parent-child-forms-when-using-playframework-with-java/35672064#35672064

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right reference!!